# Сайт не видит статику. django

Tags: python, django, apache, развертывание

Что делать, сайт не видит статику. 
Сайт стоит на alwaysdata.com. 
Сайт грузит, всё нормально, только не видит статичиские файлы.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/treader/www/treader/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Сделал collectstatic, всё собрало(в папке static появилась папка 'admin'), но на найте не отображается (http://treader.alwaysdata.net/)
На сервере стоит Apache, изменять его конфиг нельзя(нет доступа).
Что делать?

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее о том, как был установлен сайт, для тех кто не работал с alwaysdata? По-хорошему это должно настраиваться как раз в конфиге apache или nginx

Comment: @andreymal Простой хостинг сайтов, после подключения по ssh есть папки admin(/backup  /config(сдесь конфиги апач и uwsgi но их нельзя менять ` [ Error writing sites.conf: Permission denied ]
 `)  /logs  mail/) и www(в ней проект), sudo не работает для этих файлов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://treader.alwaysdata.net/static/'
```

Возможно не понадобиться:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Для настройки apache скорее всего, разрешено использовать .htaccess.

alwaysdata.com предлагает вот такое [решение](http://oldwiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Deploying_a_Django_App#Static_files)

.htaccess предлагают оформить следующим образом:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

я могу *предположить*, что нужно будет добавить строку

```
RewriteRule (static/.*)$ - [L]
```

к их решению.

Обратите внимание, что подефолту http-сервер хостинга ожидает увидеть статику в каталоге *public* корня вашего проекта на хостинге.

Comment: @ivan_sussanin А как настроить .htaccess?, c url не работает

Comment: Добавил в ответ дополнительную информацию. Вы нашли решение в подключении статики с бесплатного хостинга, только пропустили = вот тут <link rel [=]"stylesheet". Тот же принцип предлагает и хостер услуг, только таскать с этого же сервера.